# <session-timeout> in tomcat expired very quick (1 day > 7 days)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat8

I developing site in JavaEE/Spring. In **WEB-INF/web.xml** add this code:

```
<session-config>
    <!-- Week timeout -->
    <session-timeout>10080</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Yesterday I log in and tomorrow I was out of my session. But 10080 minutes = 7 days, and I should remain log in.

Comment: Did you keep your browser open as well?

Comment: @Henry, I restart my PC completely

Comment: In this case, you did no longer have the session tracking cookie in the browser and could therefore not reconnect to the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think your cookie with the session id is still valid, but after you restart your PC, your session has been invalided in tomcat server, so that you are no longer login.

Comment: Thank for you answer. But how I can retain my session when I restart PC? Some sites do it perfectly.

Comment: Which site(s) does it?